# Canonicalisation index effecting index in directory

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a  working on Canonicalisation issues that were effecting my website.

I have successfully got  http//.mywebsite.co.uk going to http://www.mywebsite.co.uk however  regarding making http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/index.php going to just http://www.mywebsite.co.uk I have a issue.

This  is what I use:

```
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
 RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works fine for the home directory but I have a sub directory for admin that uses index.php to pass commands using the query string, e.g. http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/myadminpanel/index.php?command=getaccounts.  Depending on the command I use php to included code into the index.php page.

The problem is the index.php is being removed in the sub folder and creating this:
http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/myadminpanel/?command=getaccounts.

Which is messing the page up.

Is there a way to not let the redirect the index.php page in the sub directory?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to not let the redirect the index.php page in the sub directory?

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php[/?\s]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]
```

This will only remove `index.php` in website root.